# Conditional CSS file with 'reactR'

Tags: javascript, css, r, reactjs

I'm currently doing a R package with the **reactR** package. It wraps a component of the **PrimeReact** React library (the `CascadeSelect`).

I have to choose a CSS file for the style. For example I included

```
import "primereact/resources/themes/bootstrap4-dark-purple/theme.css";
```

at the first line of my JSX file.

However I would like that the user had the choice of the style. How could I do that? From R, I can only pass the **props** to the React component. If we could `import` the CSS file inside the component, that would be an ideal solution. But I don't think this is possible.

Otherwise I have an idea that I didn't test yet. I could copy all the available **theme.css** files in the **www** folder of the R package and then include the one wanted by the user in the `stylesheet` argument of the `htmlDependency` function.